# Different config for shared angular library

Tags: angular, angular12, angular-library, angular-module, angular-config

I've 3 different libraries in 3 modules in my angular project: two separate libraries which include the same third library for some shared functionality. This third library has some configuration.

[image]

Assuming each module has a service `ServiceA`, `ServiceB` and `ServiceZ` whith a function

```
ServiceA.name(){return ServiceZ.name};
ServiceB.name(){return ServiceZ.name};
ServiceZ.name(){return config.foo};
```

Now if I call `ServiceA1.name()` the result shuld be `A1` and `ServiceA2.name()` should result in `A2`.

How can I achieve this behaviour in angular?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dzssmg?file=src/app/b/b.service.ts)

Comment: Your demo code seems to be almost there no? The only thing that probably needs to be done is to remove the providedIn: root for the service you’d like to configure. Instead, provide the service in both A modules (this way, they get their own instance)

Comment: That's what I assumed as well. Any idea what specific I have to change? I tried already `providedIn: 'any'` / `root`/ `platform`/`BModule`

Comment: Completely remove that object in the service itself and add the service in the providers arrays in the modules itself

Comment: Sadly it's the same result 